# Home door "open/close sensor" without installation

Tags: microcontroller, sensor

I want to make an application/PCB with a microcontroller circuit. The board containing the MCU will be placed inside the door lock, in one like that:

A side:

[image]

At the door frame on the wall, we have this:

B side:

[image]

I want my circuit to know if A is very near from B or not, that is, if the door is closed or open.

The picture below is a common way to make such sensor, but this idea will not be accepted for my project, I need something that will required none of sensor installation. I need a sensor that could be placed only on "A side", nothing on B side or other places. In "A side" I will be able to make openings on the metal of the lock. As can seen, B side has a free space at the middle.
Is that possible in a simple way?

The picture below shows something that I want to avoid, avoid any kind of external installation.

[image]

Would something like this work?
It is TCRT5000 of Vishay: http://www.vishay.com/docs/83760/tcrt5000.pdf

[image]

Comment: *"Would something like this work?"* Maybe, you need to give us a link to what "this" is... For all I know it's just two indicator LED's. I assume that security is a concern here? If that's an infrared detector, it would easily be bypassed with a piece of plastic. In fact the door latch is also very vulnerable to being opened with something like a small piece of plastic.

Comment: Hi. I have edited the topic with the link of the sensor. I just want the MCU to be able to know if the door is closed/open. I don't mean locked/unlocked.

Comment: How does the sensor receive power if it is fitted in the door? How will it communicate with the outside world?

Comment: The sensor requires a flat mirror to be installed on the other side, otherwise it may not trigger. You should also answer the other questions that we have...

Comment: The circuit will be supplied with a 3.7V li-ion battery, and can be charged through a USB micro connector. @RonBeyer lets see what options we have, because I have used this sensor in past and it worked reflecting directly in plastic at around 4 to 5 centimeters, without any mirror, reflecting directly in plastic surface, I think it will work as sensors of the door, but I would like to check other ideas also, to compare.

Comment: Theoretically it would work if that sensor can output a low  or high state when object is close or not close to sensor. Since this sensor works well with reflective surfaces (indicated in Datasheet and it’s test circuit), it would be advised to place a reflective surface across from it (placed inside door frame, far enough inside to not get scratched). Such could be a mirror, reflective film, plastic, paper, etc. Only thing is how you plan on placing an MCU, sensor, and battery inside that door.

Comment: The problem you are going to have without placing the reflector is distance. It may work in plastic at 4-5cm (about 2 inches), but when mounted in the door frame you are going to be very close (5mm or less). You may not get enough of the light from one side to the other. It would help if you polish the metal plate on the other side.

Comment: @RonBeyer such a sensor *does not* require an actual mirror, sure, something that is strongly reflective of IR will generate a stronger signal, but it can be done with most common materials for reasons similar to the fact that we can see them (try bouncing a TV remote off your hand).  Some effort with putty or such would get the field of view to a workable point.  Signal techniques reject ambient light, and polling/sleep logic keeps power consumption acceptable.  That said, a passive mechanical solution is simpler if it can work.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't modify the "B side" at all, then you have to rely on detecting something that's already there.

- An optical sensor can detect the painted surface, but can easily be fooled by something passing by the edge of the open door, or by light shining on it.
- A metal detector might be more reliable, and have fewer false positives when open. This will be more complicated to implement if the jamb plate is non-ferrous.
- A simple mechanical switch might be your best bet. [This type](https://www.alliedelec.com/product/edwards-signaling/44/70016390/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5c3YkcKa6QIVAZyzCh3xRg-cEAQYBCABEgIh9PD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) could be located either on the latch side or the hinge side of the door.

Comment: I was also going to mention using a switch too. You just have read my mind.

Comment: I’m surprised nobody mentioned a reed switch yet.

Comment: @StarCat: A reed switch requires a magnet on the "B side", which the OP is ruling out. But that is by far the most common type of door/window switch on the market.

Comment: @StarCat Reed switches aren't magical, they require a magnetic trigger (Dave's second point)

Comment: Ok, my thinking was a small reed switch+magnet might be fitted into the side of the door and the inside of the frame (invisible from the outside). That would be the solution I would go for.

Comment: A magnet or switch is one of the simpler and more robust ideas if the mechanics of fit are acceptable.  Either an optical or inductive sensor would require polling to keep the power consumption acceptable, fortunately that is also a chance to apply some discrimination logic, for example modulation and a filter or synchronous / lock-in detection to reject ambient light: take an ADC reading with the light on, then subtract a reading with it off, do that a few times, then sleep...